# React/preact OnClick <td> render table with details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I have a Table which when you click a td tag that is an plusbutton it should show the details about that row. Something like this:

[image]

Right now I am just testing it like this:

```
props.info.map((l, i) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{i + 1}</td>
                            <td>{l.UserId}</td>
                            <td onClick={props.onShowInfoDetails}> 
                             <MenuPlusButton /></td>
                            {props.showInfoDetails && (
                        <DetailsTable />
                        )
                        }
                        </tr>
                    )
                })
```

where the DetailsTable is the thing i want to render onClick

```
export const DetailsTable = (props: Props) => {
return (
<tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
)
```

}

There is two problems with this. First the DetailsTable renders to the right of the rest of the content and not under it like in the picture. second problem is that when I click it all table rows show the hello not just the one that I clicked. Both of these I can't seem to figure out. The second problem I guess is because it says if `props.showEntryDetails` is true it renders the DetailsTable and the onClick sets it to true but how do I make it so it's only true for that row that I clicked?

Comment: you need to first add a key prop to each tr block in your iterator then showInfoDetails should be added as a prop to your `l` object. ie onClick={ () => !l.showUserDetails } then use l.showUserDetails && instead of props.showUserDetails

Comment: @JayLane it partly works. It makes so only one of them get to render the hello but i need to manually reload the maincomponent for the hello to trigger. like if i click the onClick doesnt set it to true until its all reloaded i thought it would reload instantly